# ROS+Qt question

Tags: ros, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to develop an application in Qt that can run nodes in ROS. I know one can run the CMakeList.txt of the package in Qt as per the necessary changes shown in http://answers.ros.org/question/12790/ros-qt-creator-gui/.

I already have a developed application that has the normal .pro files. The application has loads of other algorithm codes in it and I intend to integrate this application with some Qt code to run ROS nodes. But I can not understand how to do so, as the ROS package can be run using the CMakeList.txt. I may not have enough expertise on ROS+Qt, so any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44815/ros+qt-question/) by [sen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1630/sen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although in theory it is possible to build ROS with qmake/.pro files, I'd still recommend cmake/rosbuild. This means you will need to port your .pro files to cmake.

If this is too much work, you can build the majority of your code and algorithms using qmake into libraries (without any ROS dependencies) and then only provide a ROS interface wrapper that integrates ROS via cmake and just links your libraries.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1630/sen/) on 2012-10-02**:
Thanks Dornhege. I like your suggestions and I intend to follow the second suggestion. I will let you know how it turns out.